# Combining two shell commands into a single command

Tags: bash, powershell, powershell-2.0

In Bash, we can combine two shell commands `cd` and `ls` like this:

```
function cd {
    builtin cd "$@" && ls
}
#this will get a list of file after changing into a directory
```

Also this

```
mkcd () { mkdir -p "$@" && cd "$@"; }
#this will create and directory and change into it at once
```

Can we do similar stuff in Powershell? If so, I would like to make similar functions and put it in my $profile

Thanks for any help.
Steeluser

***EDIT:***

I realized this could be done from shell like this:

```
$> pwd|ls

    Directory: D:\ps

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----          5/7/2011   9:40 PM            config                                                                    
d----          5/7/2011   9:40 PM            output                                                                    
d----          5/8/2011   3:37 AM            static                                                                    
-a---          5/8/2011   3:36 AM        485 create-static-files.ps1
```

This could be put in a profile like this:

```
function pl
{
    pwd|ls
}
```

and can be invoked from the shell

```
ps$ pl

    Directory: D:\ps

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----          5/7/2011   9:40 PM            config                                                                    
d----          5/7/2011   9:40 PM            output                                                                    
d----          5/8/2011   3:37 AM            static                                                                    
-a---          5/8/2011   3:36 AM        485 create-static-files.ps1
```

But I could not figure out how to do the mkcd function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
Function mkcd {
  mkdir $args[0]
  cd $args[0]
}
```

This is just an ordinary function in powershell.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347712.aspx for more.

Comment: It's fine, but does not manage existing directory and does return `$null`. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You may want also manage exception `directory already exists` and also return the directory object to your caller:

```
Function mkcd {
  if(!(Test-Path -path $args[0])) {
   mkdir $args[0]
  }
  cd $args[0] -passthru
}
```