# Equivalent of "&& cd $_" in Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters, mkdir, cd, automatic-variable

With bash I can create a directory and immediately enter it with `mkdir mydir && cd $_`. Is there a powershell equivalent of `$_`?

Comment: Pipe the newly-created container to `Set-Location`: `mkdir mydir | cd`.  Otherwise, does this answer your question? [Create new directory and navigate into it (Windows CMD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343185/create-new-directory-and-navigate-into-it-windows-cmd) or [Combining two shell commands into a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5924646/150605)

Comment: `mkdir mydir3 | cd -Path { $_ }` works, too, using [delay-binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) and doesn't change to using the provider path.

Comment: Another one that doesn't change to using provider path: `mkdir mydir | % fullname | cd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  Remember that `cd` is an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases) for the [`Set-Location` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location).

##### Pipe the newly-created directory to `cd`

```powershell
PS X:\> mkdir mydir | cd
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::X:\mydir>
```

Notice that after running the command the current location uses the directory's [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers) path.

If you don't like the visual clutter, you could instead...

##### Pass the newly-created directory to `-Path`

###### Via a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters)

```powershell
PS X:\> mkdir mydir | cd -Path { $_ }
PS X:\mydir>
```

`-Path` must be specified as a named parameter for this to work.

###### Via a direct parameter value

```powershell
PS X:\> cd -Path (mkdir mydir)
PS X:\mydir>
```

...or simply...

```powershell
PS X:\> cd (mkdir mydir)
PS X:\mydir>
```

##### Pipe the newly-created directory's [`FullName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname) to `cd`

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73353915/equivalent-of-cd-in-powershell#comment129544373_73353915) [@zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) suggests...

```powershell
PS X:\> mkdir mydir | % FullName | cd
PS X:\mydir>
```

...which is a shorter way of writing...

```powershell
PS X:\> mkdir mydir | ForEach-Object -MemberName 'FullName' | cd
PS X:\mydir>
```

...and works the same as...

```powershell
PS X:\> mkdir mydir | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName' | cd
PS X:\mydir>
```

...and much the same as...

```powershell
PS X:\> (mkdir mydir).FullName | cd
PS X:\mydir>
```

##### Use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object#notes) to pass the `$_` [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) to both `mkdir` and `cd`

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51386184/150605) to [Create new directory and navigate into it (Windows CMD)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51343185/150605) [@Shenk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5652697/shenk) suggests...

```powershell
PS X:\> echo mydir | % { mkdir $_; cd $_ }


    Directory: X:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         8/15/2022   2:35 PM                mydir


PS X:\mydir>
```

...which can be simplified to...

```powershell
'mydir' | % { mkdir $_; cd $_ }
```

...and is much the same as...

```powershell
$name = 'mydir'; mkdir $name; cd $name
```

###### Considerations

Notice that, unlike the other solutions, because the output of `mkdir` is not captured by a variable, pipeline, parameter, etc. it is written to the console.  If this is undesirable, you'll need to explictly suppress that output with something like...

```powershell
'mydir' | % { mkdir $_; cd $_ } | Out-Null
```

...or...

```powershell
'mydir' | % { mkdir $_; cd $_ } > $null
```

Also, if `mkdir` fails then `cd` could be unconditionally executed, anyways.  For example, this...

```powershell
PS X:\> 'Directory name with invalid characters ?*' | % { mkdir $_; cd $_ }
mkdir : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:51
+ 'Directory name with invalid characters ?*' | % { mkdir $_; cd $_ }
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (X:\Directory na...d characters ?*:String) [New-Item], ArgumentExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

cd : Cannot find path 'Directory name with invalid characters ?*' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:61
+ 'Directory name with invalid characters ?*' | % { mkdir $_; cd $_ }
+                                                             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Directory name ...d characters ?*:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

PS X:\>
```

...produces two errors, not one, after the directory could not be created due to an invalid name, and this...

```powershell
PS X:\> 'Directory name that already exists' | % { mkdir $_; cd $_ }
mkdir : An item with the specified name X:\Directory name that already exists already exists.
At line:1 char:44
+ 'Directory name that already exists' | % { mkdir $_; cd $_ }
+                                            ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (X:\Directory name that already exists:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

PS X:\Directory name that already exists>
```

...changes the current directory even after `mkdir` failed to create a directory that already exists.

Comment: Nicely done. As for `mkdir mydir | cd`  unexpectedly showing the provider prefix in the prompt string / in `$PWD`: this should be considered a _bug_: see [GitHub issue #10522](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10522). Maybe worth noting, as an aside: on Unix-like platforms, `mkdir` defers to the platform native utility of that name, which doesn't produce output; there, `New-Item -TypeDirectory ...` is required instead.